# Get original values from entity with Hibernate Envers

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate-envers

I have configured *Hibernate Envers* in my *Springboot* project and now it is saving each change in the entities I annotated with *@Audited* but, I have a doubt.

Envers stores the revision of the entity *after* the first change is done so, after one change I have the new values stored in the entity table and in the _AUD table. The next changes are stored in the _AUD table so I know what changed after the first update but the original values (the ones *before* the first change) are lost. Am I missing something? Is there a way to save the values *before* the change is done (as I already have the last values in the entity table)?.

Comment: Do you have a row in your _AUD table with a `REVTYPE=0` or are they all either `REVTYPE=1` or `REVTYPE=2`?

Comment: @Naros There are only 1s and 2s, so... it looks like Envers is not auditing creation, could it be?

Comment: Yes.  How is the record being inserted into the table to start?  Is the record an entity maintained in a collection by chance?

Comment: @Naros I found the problem. There is a process that inserts rows in the DB and Envers does not seem to know about it, so it does not audit these actions. Thank you for pointing me to the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three different revision types tracked by Envers:

- ADD (REVTYPE=0) - INSERT
- MOD (REVTYPE=1) - UPDATE
- DEL (REVTYPE=2) - DELETE

This implies that if the entries are being inserted, updated, and deleted by Hibernate through a stateful session, Envers will pickup those changes and add the appropriate `REVTYPE` entry to the audit table.

If an entry is being manipulated outside of the scope of Hibernate's stateful session, Envers won't know about that change and the corresponding entry won't be added to the audit table.  Based on the comments, this is why you don't see a `REVTYPE=0` (aka `INSERT`) operation.

For situations like this, you'll need to make sure that you increment the revision number sequence and add the appropriate entries manually through your script or batch process that is inserting the row in order to guarantee that the Envers schema has the complete visibility to the entity's history.